# How to make the v-col content scrollable?

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js

I've created UI based on vuetify that looks as follows:

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  vuetify: new Vuetify(),
  
})
```

```html
<link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:300,400,500,700|Material+Icons' rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue/dist/vue.js"></script>
<link href="https://unpkg.com/vuetify/dist/vuetify.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
 <script src="https://unpkg.com/vuetify/dist/vuetify.min.js"></script>

<div id="app">
<v-app>
   <v-app-bar
      color="deep-purple accent-4"
      dark app
    >
      <v-app-bar-nav-icon></v-app-bar-nav-icon>

      <v-toolbar-title>Page title</v-toolbar-title>


    </v-app-bar>

  <!-- Sizes your content based upon application components -->
  <v-content>

    <!-- Provides the application the proper gutter -->
    <v-container fluid>
      <v-row justify="start">
        <v-col>
        <v-card max-width="300" class="mx-auto">
    <v-list-item>
      <v-list-item-icon>
        <v-icon large color="teal darken-2">mdi-email</v-icon>
      </v-list-item-icon>

      <v-list-item-content>
        <v-list-item-title class="headline">Messages</v-list-item-title>

        <v-list-item-subtitle>overview of all messages</v-list-item-subtitle>
      </v-list-item-content>
    </v-list-item>

    <v-card-text>
      <v-row align="center" justify="center" no-gutters>
        <v-col cols="5">
          <p class="title">SYSTEM1</p>
        </v-col>

        <v-col cols="5">
          <p class="subtitle-1">111111111111</p>
        </v-col>
      </v-row>

      <v-row justify="center" no-gutters>
        <v-col cols="5">
          <p class="title">SYSTEM2</p>
        </v-col>

        <v-col cols="5">
          <p class="subtitle-1">111111111</p>
        </v-col>
      </v-row>
    </v-card-text>
  </v-card>
</v-col>
  
        <v-col>
        <v-card max-width="300" class="mx-auto">
    <v-list-item>
      <v-list-item-icon>
        <v-icon large color="teal darken-2">mdi-email</v-icon>
      </v-list-item-icon>

      <v-list-item-content>
        <v-list-item-title class="headline">Messages</v-list-item-title>

        <v-list-item-subtitle>overview of all messages</v-list-item-subtitle>
      </v-list-item-content>
    </v-list-item>

    <v-card-text>
      <v-row align="center" justify="center" no-gutters>
        <v-col cols="5">
          <p class="title">SYSTEM1</p>
        </v-col>

        <v-col cols="5">
          <p class="subtitle-1">111111111111</p>
        </v-col>
      </v-row>

      <v-row justify="center" no-gutters>
        <v-col cols="5">
          <p class="title">SYSTEM2</p>
        </v-col>

        <v-col cols="5">
          <p class="subtitle-1">111111111</p>
        </v-col>
      </v-row>
    </v-card-text>
  </v-card>
</v-col>
      </v-row>
      <v-row>
        
      <v-col cols="6">
          <p class="title">
          Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.
            Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.
            Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.
 Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.
            Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.
            Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.
 Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.
            Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.
            Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.
          </p>
        </v-col>
        
      </v-row>
    </v-container>
  </v-content>

  <v-footer app>
    <!-- -->
  </v-footer>
</v-app>
</div>
```

My question is, the row with the content:

```
<v-row>

    <v-col cols="6">
        <p class="title">
            Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum. Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum. Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.
        </p>
    </v-col>

</v-row>
```

how to make it scrollable? So the whole page should not be scrollable, but only the content of the row, that I mentioned above, should be scrollable. It should also take the remaining spaces of the `v-container`, that means for example:

```
v-container = 100%
v-row(the first row) = 300px
```

so the second row should be `100% - 300px`, I know, it is not the same unit. 
How to archive it?